# Power BI - keep a permanent row visible in a matrix even when filtering

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am now working on my first Power BI project and for 2 weeks I have been struggling to find a solution for the following situation:

I have a matrix in which I show on the rows the Department, the Resource and then the Projects for each resource. In the columns I have the time information: year, quarter, month. In the values I have a measure on which there is also a certain color coding applied.

[image]

When selecting values from the Projects slicer or other slicers with Project details, the data in the matrix shows only the corresponding rows, which is normal. 
However, I need it to always show two specific Projects rows (Capacity and Total - as shown in the example picture) for each Resource, plus the other selections made in the Projects slicer, which could be multiple.
This is required because any information in the matrix needs to be compared to those two Project rows which show different values by Resource.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: I would advice you to have a second visual element where you have the rows which always need to be shown.

Comment: Aldert, thank you for your response! I am not sure I understand what you mean regarding the 2nd visual element. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Like a second matrix or table..

Comment: My matrix will have to respond to filters so the two permanent project rows corresponding to each resource will not always be in the same place. If in total I fave 100 resources, for example, when I select project X from the slicer, the matrix will have to show the resources which are assigned to that project X, let's say 10 resources, and for each of these 10 resources, there will be a row with values for the selected project X and the 2 other rows for the permanent projects for each resource,let's say projects A and B. So, in this case the matrix will show for each resource 3 rows.

Comment: Try checking paginated reports in power BI, Which seems to be more inline with your requirement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi

Comment: @VirginiaBI - it's very hard to help you without seeing your data model and all relevant measures. Data sample to reproduce the report (or pbix test file) would be valuable too.